# Python lazy parameter initialization strange order of execution behavior

Tags: python, oop, pytorch, pycharm

**TLDR** - Code that should not be running, runs while class initializing

I have two classes, one base class (that should be abstract) and one class that inherit from him.

```
import logging

import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class TsDataSetBase(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__labels: torch.Tensor = None
        self.__data: torch.Tensor = None
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.data[idx], self.labels[idx]
    
    def get_as_tensor(self):
        """
        load a single file as a tensor
        """
        raise RuntimeError("this is a base class")
    
    @property
    def labels(self) -> torch.Tensor:
        if self.__labels is None or self.__data is None:
            self.__labels, self.__data = self.get_as_tensor()
        return self.__labels
    
    @property
    def data(self) -> torch.Tensor:
        if self.__labels is None or self.__data is None:
            self.__labels, self.__data = self.get_as_tensor()
        return self.__data
    
    @property
    def tensors(self):
        """
        This is here to fit the TensorDataset object
        """
        return self.data, self.labels
```

This is the Son:

```
import logging

from data_loaders.TsDataSetBase import TsDataSetBase

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class UcrDataSet(TsDataSetBase):

  def __init__(self, path_to_ds):
    super().__init__()
    self.path_to_ds = path_to_ds
    print("so strange")
    self._train = 123
    print("end of init")

  def get_as_tensor(self):
    filepath = self.path_to_ds
    print("strange")
    logger.info(f"converting csv file to tensor {filepath}")
    return None, None


def build_new_ds(path_to_ds: str) -> TsDataSetBase:
   return UcrDataSet(path_to_ds)
```

Now when I execute the following line:

```
ds = build_new_ds(dataset_to_test)
```

I get this extremely strange output:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 202.7660.27)
so strange
strange
strange
strange
strange
```

When I try to use a breakpoint it doesn't stop, I am using Pycharm.
This really makes me curious about what exactly is going on, is it an issue with my environment or something else?

Thanks a lot

Comment: *"Code that should not be running, runs while class initializing"* What is running that shouldn't be running exactly?

Comment: the method get_as_tensor gets called and it shouldn't be called

Comment: This is not reproducible, at least on my end I am getting  `'so strange'` and `'end of init'`. How are you running your code?